# Копирование ячейки из одного листа в диапазон другого листа в Google Spreadsheets (Таблицы)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Нужно взять ячейку А1 в листе 1 и заполнить инфой из неё (скопировать во все ячейки) диапазон А1:С80 в листе 2. Ни одна из тестируемых формул не подошла, возможно ли это сделать через скрипты? Если возможно, то где и как научится это делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не представляю, какой комментарий тут может быть. Но, положим, этот метод мне нравится больше всего

```js
function myFunction() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const from = book.getRange('Sheet1!A1');
  const to = book.getRange('Sheet2!A1:C80');
  from.copyTo(to);
}
```

https://youtu.be/vNxWYrZT46Q

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]